# computing integral without softwares: $\int \frac{2x+3}{x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration

I was wondering if this integral can be solve without wolfram and others:

$$\int \frac{2x+3}{x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Thanks.

Comment: The result is a very large formula which is hard to write and to obtain by hand using only pen and paper. In this sense the only way is using computer algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a plan of attack, at least:

1) Separate into two terms, and to find $\displaystyle\int\frac{2x}{x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$, let $u=x^2$ to get $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{u+\sqrt{1-u}} du$, and then let $t=\sqrt{1-u}$ to obtain $$ 2\int\frac{t}{t^2-t-1} dt.$$
Now use partial fractions.

2) For the second term, let $x=\sin\theta$ to get $\displaystyle3\int\frac{1}{x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx=3\int\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^{2}\theta+\cos\theta} d\theta$.

Next let $\theta=\tan\frac{t}{2}, \sin\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},  \cos\theta=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, d\theta=\frac{2}{1+t^2} dt$ to get
 $$\int\frac{2(1-t^2)}{4t^2+(1+t^2)(1-t^2)} dt=2\int\frac{t^2-1}{t^4-4t^2-1} dt.$$
Now use partial fractions.

Comment: but how do you continue the last integral?

Comment: You can factor $t^4-4t^2-1$ as $(t^2-2)^2-5=(t^2-(2+\sqrt{5}))(t^2+(\sqrt{5}-2))=(t-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}})(t+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}})(t^2+(\sqrt{5}-2))$, and then write $\frac{t^2-1}{t^4-4t^2-1}$ as $\frac{A}{t-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}}+\frac{B}{t+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}}+\frac{Ct+D}{t^2+(\sqrt{5}-2)}$ and continue with partial fractions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Amplify with the conjugate, and then make an appropriate trigonometric substitution.

Comment: What appropriate substitution would you suggest?

Comment: i don't see how does it help

Comment: @abii: After breaking up the parentheses and separating the initial integral into $4$ smaller ones, you'll be left with two rational integrands, which are trivial, and two for which an obvious trigonometric substitution is in order.